# Unknown Display 1024x768 External Monitor (Mirror Display)

Tags: settings, display, intel, resolution

- PC: Lenovo Laptop G510
- CPU: Intel Core i5 HD 4600 graphics
- Res: 1366x768
  So, I have an RCA small TV connected via VGA port that I use as a monitor since my laptop's built-in screen is messed up. For a few days, it was working perfectly fine, it detected the TV as RCA; and when I mirrored the display the res was fine.

Recently out of nowhere the RCA TV says "Unknown Display" and the res is set to 1024x768, I cannot change it to 1366x768, how it usually was.

Any help is appreciated, I don't know what to do.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Same exact problem but with main external screen. I have a ZOTAC GeForce GTX 1060 3GB, intel i3-8100, 16GB RAM. Worked like a charm in live mode, but with nvidia drivers installed now is in this crooked resolution on a full 1080p screen.